# UNO Xamarin Platform 'MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent' error for Android Mac and iOS

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, uno

I want to build a Project, that will run on all Platforms, so I chose UNO, I am able to build the Project in UWP and Wasm, but when I want to build in Android I get the
'MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent' error
I have no Idea what to do, here is my C# and Xaml code for "MainPage.xaml"

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace MyProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyProject.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyProject"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Content="Test" Click="Button_Click" Margin="10,0,10,10" FontSize="30" CanDrag="True" x:Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="53" />
        <TimePicker Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="32"/>
    </Grid>
 
</Page>
```

Comment: Do you get this error after an actual Build or is it just an IntelliSense error?

Comment: @Batesias, my solution (which I created using Uno project template) builds OK but code behind App.xaml in a Shared project still does not recognize 'InitializeComponent' method. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @DmitryMatveev If your code builds and runs, it's probably not a real problem. You can probably just ignore the red squigglies. What I usually do to avoid that problem is make sure my file is scoped to the UWP project (the drop-down in the top left corner of the text editor).

Comment: @Batesias I found out that changing build action on App.xaml while target platform is selected resolves a problem... must be something to do with uno code generator.